# Why is this not logging to the console when a reaction is added to a message?

Tags: discord.js

The current code is not logging to the console when a reaction is added to a message.

I know the messageReactionAdd event is triggered by calling the event separately underneath, however I am not sure why this is not logging.

```js
  // This makes the events used a bit more readable
  const events = {
    ADD: 'messageReactionAdd',
    REMOVE: 'messageReactionRemove',
  };

  // This event handles adding/removing users from the role(s) they chose
  client.on('raw', async event => {

    if (!events.hasOwnProperty(event.t)) return;

    const { d: data } = event;
    const user = client.users.get(data.user_id);
    const channel = client.channels.get(data.channel_id);

    const message = await channel.fetchMessage(data.message_id);
    const member = message.guild.members.get(user.id);

    const emojiKey = (data.emoji.id) ? `${data.emoji.name}:${data.emoji.id}` : data.emoji.name;
    let reaction = message.reactions.get(emojiKey);

    if (!reaction) {
      // Create an object that can be passed through the event like normal
      const emoji = new Emoji(client.guilds.get(data.guild_id), data.emoji);
      reaction = new MessageReaction(message, emoji, 1, data.user_id === client.user.id);
    }

    if(event.t === 'ADD') {
      console.log("Reaction: Added")
    }
  });
```

There is no errors, console completely blank.

Answer (score 2):

For what it seems, you are using `if (!events.hasOwnProperty(event.t)) return;` to check if `event.t` is equal to any of them, but when someome react in a message `event.t` returns `MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD`. So it's coming back from the beginning.
"Just change the `ADD` property to fix IT"

But, in `if(event.t === 'ADD')` you check if `event.t` is equal to `ADD`, So this will not execute, since `event.p` returns `MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD`

"Just change the `if(event.t === 'ADD')` to `if(event.p === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD) {`

Make this to fix your code.